# Which method to find duplicate integers is more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashset

As it's often the case, there are different solutions to a problem. Mine is to find duplicate integers. I have 2 approaches.

The first one is to sort an array of integers and compare. The 2nd one is just to use a HashSet. Could you please tell me which is more efficient and why? Note that the original array **must not** be overwritten.

**Main class**

```
public class Main {
    static DuplicateNumbers dn;
    static DuplicateNumbersHash dnh;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayOfIntegers = {9, 7, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9};

        // 1st class test
        dn = new DuplicateNumbers(arrayOfIntegers);
        dn.searchForDuplicates();

        System.out.println("\n\n2nd test\n\n");

        // 2nd class test
        dnh = new DuplicateNumbersHash(arrayOfIntegers);
        dnh.searchForDuplicates();

    }
} // Main class
```

**Non-HashSet** approach

```
public class DuplicateNumbers {
    protected int[] arrayOfIntegers;

    public DuplicateNumbers(int[] arrayOfIntegers) {
        this.arrayOfIntegers = arrayOfIntegers;
    }

    public void searchForDuplicates() {
        // do not overwrite original array, so create a temp one instead
        int[] tempArray = new int[arrayOfIntegers.length];
        System.arraycopy(arrayOfIntegers, 0, tempArray, 0,
        arrayOfIntegers.length);

        // sorting temp array only
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);

        // now look for duplicates
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (tempArray[i] == tempArray[i + 1]) {
                System.out.printf(
                    "Duplicates: tempArray[%d] and tempArray[%d]\n", i,
                    i + 1);
                System.out.printf("Repeated value: %d %d\n", tempArray[i],
                    tempArray[i + 1]);
                System.out.println();
            } // if
        } // for
    } // searchForDuplicates()
} // DuplicateNumbers class
```

**HashSet** approach; the previous class is inherited to paste less code here

```
public class DuplicateNumbersHash extends DuplicateNumbers {
    public DuplicateNumbersHash(int[] arrayOfIntegers)  {
        super(arrayOfIntegers);
    }

    @Override
    public void searchForDuplicates() {
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIntegers.length; i++) {
                if (!s.add(arrayOfIntegers[i])) {
                    System.out.printf("Repeated value: %d\n", arrayOfIntegers[i]);
            }
        }

        s = null;
    }
}
```

Which one is better? Is there an even better solution?

Comment: I would say to you to profile them and check the best one but IMO you should use the `Set` approach (assuming you're not using a `TreeSet`).

Comment: If you value speed, then I'd go with Luiggi's suggestion and profile it.

From a memory standpoint though, having a `Set` is better, since you don't necessarily need as much space as a second copy of all of the elements.

Comment: @DennisMeng The sort method would be worse asymptomatically. It'd be O(nlogn) whereas the set approach will be O(n)

Comment: @DennisMeng - I think you have it backwards. A `Set` will need to contain all numbers (except for duplicates). However, the sort-based approach requires sorting, which is O(n log n), while a `Set`-based approach is O(n).

Comment: Yeah, I realized I underthought it. Fixed now.

Comment: @TedHopp Depends on the set implementation. For example membership testing in C++ std libraries is O(log n) because they're implemented with binary trees. In CPython it's O(1) because they're implemented with associative arrays.

Comment: @ShashankGupta - The question was specifically about using `HashSet` in Java, which has O(1) membership testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best sorting algorithm is `O(n log n)` in time complexity, so the sort method would also be `O(n logn)`. The HashSet approach will be `O(n)` in complexity. So you should ideally use the HashSet approach.

Comment: +1 for being the right answer for asymptotic complexity (as n gets large). For 10 integers (which is OP's specific example), it's not clear which has the best performance (not that it matters all that much, unless finding duplicates among 10 numbers is part of some performance-critical inner loop code).

Comment: All right, it makes more sense now. I wonder why my question got a -1 though. Anyway, thank you for pointing out differences.

Answer (score 1):

The Hash-set implementation is more time efficient, however the array-sort implementation is is more efficient in terms of memory usage.

Time: Adding a value to a hash-set has a constant complexity, O(1) - it doesn't matter how big the hash set is.  However, arrayCopy has a linear complexity, O(n).  Also, depending on how you sort the array, that will also take some time.

Memory: Your array implementation only uses double the memory of the orginal array.  Your hash set will likely be much bigger than the original array.